# Converting ArcGIS Online Basemap to new coordinate system for ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have an ArcGIS web application that depends on all coordinate systems of the layers and basemaps to be the same, which I would think is standard practice.

I like to just use the Esri online basemaps such as [this one](http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/0), but it uses 102100 for a coordinate system instead of 4326, which is what I have all my other layers in.

Is there a way I can transform these Esri basemaps into a new coordinate system and publish them to my server via ArcMap?

Am I doing something wrong here and I should be taking a whole different approach, because I would expect other people to run into the same issue as this all the time if they want to use Esri basemaps.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191720/converting-arcgis-online-basemap-to-new-coordinate-system-for-arcmap/204244#comment289781_191720):

> The Esri basemaps are in the same spherical Mercator projection as
>   Google Maps and Bing Maps. For performance reasons, you generally want
>   to project vectors to the basemap raster (which is the whole benefit
>   of basemaps). You can publish your own basemap, but it's not a trivial
>   effort.